# What is the correct signature for this function?

Tags: haskell

This code fails to compile with this error

```
src/JsonParser.hs:33:37-62: error:
    * Couldn't match type `b1' with `b'
      `b1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          resultantRunParse :: forall b1. String -> Maybe (String, b1)
        at src/JsonParser.hs:29:5-52
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
        at src/JsonParser.hs:27:11-42
      Expected type: Maybe (String, b1)
        Actual type: Maybe (String, b)
```

The code:

```
import Prelude

newtype Parser a = Parser
  { runParser :: String -> Maybe (String, a)
  }

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser resultantRunParse where
    -- THIS FUNCTION TYPE DECLARATION IS THE PROBLEM
    -- IF I REMOVE THE TYPE DECLARATION, IT WORKS
    resultantRunParse :: String -> Maybe (String, b)
    resultantRunParse input = 
      case p input of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (remaining, parsed) -> Just (remaining, f parsed)
```

I tried the signature `resultantRunParse :: forall b1. String -> Maybe (String, b1)` suggested in the error message and that also didnt work.

Also, making the `resultantRunParse = undefined` and keeping the type signature also worked. Very strange!

What is the correct signature for this function?

Answer (score 9):

The type signature must contain `b`, but it must be the same one as the `b` used in the enclosing function. This is impossible without scoped type variables:

https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables

To us this, add a comment to the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

Then, use an explicit `forall b.` in the enclosing function’s type signature.

Without scoped type variables, there is no way to write `b` in the type signature and make it the **same** `b` as the one used in the enclosing function.

(My personal recommendation is to just not use a type signature here. It is not necessary.)

Comment: This was not the problem in my case actually, I had this extension enabled in the cabal file. But I think I found the problem. My signature of `fmap` was incorrect. Should be `forall a b.` Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I believe `forall b.` is enough. Only `b` is used.

Comment: You need to quantify both, GHC has a [`forall`-or-nothing rule](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/explicit_forall.html#the-forall-or-nothing-rule): if a type has an outermost, explicit `forall.` then all type variables in the type must be listed

Answer (score 2):

First get comfortable writing the instance by hand, then you can derive it. This type looks a lot like [`StateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Strict.html#t:StateT), the state monad transformer where the order of the tuple is swapped.

```
type    StateT :: Type -> MonadTransformer
newtype StateT s m a = StateT (s -> m (a, s))
```

Your `Functor Parser` instance can be [*derived via* it](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) if you are willing to swap the order

```
{-# Language DerivingVia              #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Kind

type    Parser :: Type -> Type
newtype Parser a = Parser
  { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String)
  }
  deriving Functor
  via StateT String Maybe
```

You can derive more instances in this manner.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Catch
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Kind
import Data.Monoid

newtype Parser a = Parser ..
  deriving
    ( Functor, Applicative, Alternative
    , Monad, MonadPlus, MonadFix, MonadThrow
    , MonadFail, MonadError (), MonadState String )
  via StateT String Maybe

  -- pointwise lifting
  --   (<>)   = liftA2 (<>)
  --   mempty = pure mempty
  -- deriving (Semigroup, Monoid, Num, Bounded)
  -- via Ap Parser a

  -- or Alternative
  --   (<>)   = (<|>)
  --   mempty = empty
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via Ap Parser a
```

See the output of [`:instances` command](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances)

- `:instances StateT String Maybe`
- `:instances Ap Parser _`
- `:instances Alt Parser _`

The last two require partial type signatures `:set -XPartialTypeSignatures -Wno-partial-type-signatures`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Very theoretical, I need to read up slowly :)